# execute bash commands sequentially inside for loop in Python

Tags: python, bash

I am trying to run 2 bash commands sequentially in a for loop in Python. The loop is as given below:

```
for dataset in data:
        subprocess.call("cd " +dataset+'.matrix',shell=True)
        subprocess.call("cat part-r-* > combined_output", shell=True)
```

However, in this way, each command is being considered independently of each other. I need them to execute one after the other. I don't know how to use the subprocess module well (I also tried with os.system). I went through some documentation online but they weren't really useful. Any help in this would be appreciated. thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe they're running asynchronously (at the same time), just that they're in different subprocesses which each inherit the parent process' working directory. So it *is* waiting for the `cd` to complete, but the subprocess which has `cd`'d then disappears.

Thankfully, in this case you can tell the call to operate in a different directory with the [`cwd` parameter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments), so you don't need your `cd`:

```
for dataset in data:
    subprocess.call("cat part-r-* > combined_output",shell=True,cwd=dataset+'.matrix')
```

Answer (score 0):

An example with `os.system`:

```
import os
os.system("echo aaa > ~/SOMEFILE1111; cd ~/; cat SOMEFILE1111; rm SOMEFILE1111")
```

and one with `subprocess.call`:

```
import subprocess
cmds = [ "echo aaa > ~/SOMEFILE1111", "cd ~/",
        "cat SOMEFILE1111", "rm SOMEFILE1111"]
subprocess.call(";".join(cmds), shell=True)
```

Comment: is it OK if I write like this:                                              os.system("cd " +dataset+ '.matrix';"cat part-r-* > combined_output")

Comment: It should be like this: `"cd " +dataset+ '.matrix; cat part-r-* > combined_output'`